# Flutter : How to get the format of the scanned barcode using flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, qr-code, barcode

I am trying to build a barcode scanner app which scans the barcode using the camera, i managed to get my hands on some of the barcode plugins in flutter but they all seem to return the results as a string and there isn't a plugin which detects the format of the barcode as well, is there a way to get around this?

**Update** : pubspec.yaml

```
name: qr_code_scanner
description: QR code scanner that can be embedded inside flutter. It uses zxing in Android and MTBBarcode scanner in iOS.
version: 0.0.12
author: Julius Canute <juliuscanute at touchcapture.net>
homepage: https://juliuscanute.com
repository: https://github.com/juliuscanute/qr_code_scanner

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  plugin:
    androidPackage: net.touchcapture.qr.flutterqr
    pluginClass: FlutterQrPlugin
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what packages you are trying to use, what types of bar codes you are trying to scan and what type of results you are getting. In most cases string is all you when it comes to scanning the barcodes.

Comment: I'm using a package caller : FlutterQrPlugin :
my pubspec.yaml 
`repository: https://github.com/juliuscanute/qr_code_scanner` 
`environment: sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0" `
`dependencies: `
      `flutter: `
         `sdk: flutter`
`flutter: `
     `plugin: androidPackage: net.touchcapture.qr.flutterqr `
      `pluginClass: FlutterQrPlugin`

Comment: Thanks for additional info. It is still not exactly clear what is that you are trying to "get around". Why getting result as a string is not working for you?

Comment: With this library i am only getting the result (barcode number) and not the type of the scanned barcode for example EAN13, i want my output to be like this:
Barcode number : 86924557689192
Type : EAN13

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing the same problem, i was able to solve this by changing the kotlin code provided by that library, and instead of returning the barcode/qr-code number i added the type of the scanned code:

```
private fun createBarCodeView(): BarcodeView? {
 val barcode = BarcodeView(registrar.activity())
 barcode.decodeContinuous(
 object : BarcodeCallback {
    override fun barcodeResult(result: BarcodeResult) {
      var output = result.text + "____"+result?.barcodeFormat.toString() // <== this did the trick
  channel.invokeMethod("onRecognizeQR", output)
                    }
  override fun possibleResultPoints(resultPoints: List<ResultPoint>) {}
                }
        )
        return barcode
    }
```

Comment: Would have been good if you could make the modified version available somewhere. I need the same and figured out the code but don't know how to proceed further.